# PowerBI Incremental Refresh Duplicates

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have setup a PowerBI dataset with incremental refresh following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-configure and ensured that all tables have RangeStart > x and RangeEnd <= x to ensure only one side has the =.  I continued to investigate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-troubleshoot and noticed there is a comment

> With a refresh operation, only data that has changed at the data source is refreshed in the dataset. As the data is divided by a date, it’s recommended post (transaction) dates are not changed.

Which to me sounds extremely limiting.  Our data has two date fields LastModified and RowCreatedAt that are both date/time columns.  Last Modified is the real date/time of the last modification to the data in the row.  RowCreatedAt is the real date/time of when that modification was persisted to the database.  These can be very different (eg, if the customer is new, but has legacy data, the LastModified date may be very old, but RowCreatedAt will be very recent).

I decided to go with the RowCreatedAt value since that is something that we control (eg, if we were to refresh LastModifiedDate and load in historical data, it would never be imported to PowerBI after the initial refresh).  Both the LastModifiedDate and RowCreatedAt fields are updated when data changes in the system (eg, sales order gets a new line item added to it).

My expectation was that when data changed and the partition date was updated, it would properly update the data in the dataset (eg, remove the old row and insert the new row since the same primary key, but other data is changed).  This seems completely normal and expected behavior, but from the documentation, it seems like you can only import data which is not ever going to change or you have to refresh your history to the point where the change occurred.  This seems like a crazy limitation (eg, who has unchanging data for all time??) so I'm hopefully just misunderstanding something.